# Migrating PHP serialization from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.6

Tags: php, serialization, migration

I have a complex structure that is saved in the MySQL database using the serialize() function and then converted back using unserialize().  After migrating the system from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.6 and unserializing in 5.6 the the data that was serialized on 5.3, the structures are corrupted.  Certain references to objects now appear as arrays instead.

My questions are:

1. Is there a specification about different encoding used by serialization/unserialization in the different PHP versions?  (Could not find anything specific enough in my Google searches or in the documentation on PHP.net)
2. How do I convert serialized data from the PHP 5.3 encoding to the PHP 5.6 encoding?

Comment: Hello,
Can you provide more information about what is beeing serialized? Is it a class or just an array of data?

Comment: When you deserialize the objects, you must include the class definitions in the code. So if you're testing outside your regular code base from where you stored the objects, or if you have changed the object structure then they won't deserialize correctly. If you need to change object structure, keep the old objects, and then recreate new objects using new structure and reserialize. (Not posting as an answer as I'm not in a position to test it - but they are things to look for!)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the serialization of objects was changed in PHP5.6.  Specifically a number of areas related to serialization of objects were tided up in PHP5.6

There is a vague note mentioning this in the [PHP unserialize manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php):

> 5.6.0 Manipulating the serialised data by replacing C: with O: to force object instantiation without calling the constructor will now
>   fail.

However a look at the bugs list reveals a little more went on under the hood in [report 68099](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68099). It also states that the original format has no official documentation:

> "the original behavior (that we allow the old serialize format to be
>   used for classes using the new format) was never documented nor
>   officially supported,"

Note that the end result of that discussion was **"Won't fix"**.

So basically, your options are:

- Try one of the other serializers as a way of exporting the data between PHP versions. Such as [session_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-encode.php) which can also handle objects.
- A conversion script. There is an extensively documented version of
  the current format on [PHP internals](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/classes_objects/serialization.html), which you could use with an
  iterator on the old format to update the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the serialized data to JSON (using an installation of PHP 5.3), save that to the database and then do the opposit (using an installation of PHP 5.6).

From 5.3 to JSON :

```
$data = unserialize($strSerializedData);
$jsonData = json_encode($data);
```

From JSON to 5.6 :

```
$data = json_decode($jsonData);
$strSerializedData= serialize($data );
```

You might need to adjust the options you send to json_decode to match the original data.

This option would depend on what data is being serialized. If your data is classes, this wouldn't work.

Also, you problem could be related to this note in the documentation ([here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php#refsect1-function.unserialize-changelog)) :

> 5.6.0 Manipulating the serialised data by replacing C: with O: to force object instantiation without calling the constructor will now fail.

Comment: As the question is about serliazation/deserialisation of objects, and you correctly indicate "If your data is classes, this wouldn't work." then yeah - this won't work. You could create a "toJSON()" method and "fromJSON()" in the class and use that to access the internals, but if you go that far, then you may as well write you own serliaze/deserialize functions! And to do that, use the `serializable` interface (http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php)

Comment: Agreed that this wouldn't work for a class. The question would need clarification.

Comment: It is indeed an object from a class that I am serializing.  The object has references to objects of the same class and also to other classes.  Some of these classes in turn reference back to the object the references them.  Using serialize(), the these cross references are denoted by r: followed by a number.  Some of these references are corrupted when unserializing them the in php 5.6, and what should be a class-object in an array instead.

Comment: Are you sure the files containing classe definition are getting loaded at the correct time? You should definetly update your question to provide more detail